# Jama and Commons Math don't give desired result for relatively big matrix

Tags: java, matrix, linear-algebra, jama, apache-commons-math

I am using Jama and Apache Commons Math to solve linear algebra equations. They both work fine when the matrix is small (4x4). But not when it is relatively big (25x25). Below are my implemenations:

Jama:

```
    public double[][] solve(double[][] startState, double[][] input){
    double[][] answer = new double[1][input.length-1];
    Matrix A = new Matrix(input);
    Matrix B = new Matrix(startState);
    Matrix X = A.solve(B);
    answer = X.getArray();
    return answer;
}
```

This works fine for:

```
    double[][] startState = {{1},{2},{1},{2}};
    double[][] input = {{1,1,0,0},{1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,},{0,0,1,1}};
    double[][] answer = new JamaSolution().solve(startState, input);
```

But it fails for:

```
    double[][] startState = { {0},{1},{2},{0},{2}, {0},{2},{1},{1},{0}, {0},{2},{1},{2},{2}, {1},{1},{1},{1},{2}, {1},{2},{1},{0},{0} };
    double[][] input={
             {1,1,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {1,1,1,0,0, 0,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,1,1,1,0, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,1,1,1, 0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,

             {1,0,0,0,0, 1,1,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,1,0,0,0, 1,1,1,0,0, 0,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,1,0,0, 0,1,1,1,0, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,1,1,1, 0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,

             {0,0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 1,1,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0,0, 1,1,1,0,0, 0,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,1,1,1,0, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,1,1,1, 0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,0} ,

             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 1,1,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0,0, 1,1,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,1,1,1,0, 0,0,1,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,1,1,1, 0,0,0,1,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,0,1} ,

             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 1,1,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,1,1,1,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,1,1,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,1} ,

    };
```

Commons Math:

```
    public void solve(double[] startState, double[][] input){
        RealMatrix coefficients = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(input, false);
        DecompositionSolver solver = new LUDecomposition(coefficients).getSolver();
        RealVector constants = new ArrayRealVector(startState, false);
        RealVector solution = solver.solve(constants);
    }
```

This works fine for:

```
    double[] startState = {1,2,1,2};
    double[][] input = {{1,1,0,0},{1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,},{0,0,1,1}};
```

But fails for:

```
    double[] startState = { 0,1,2,0,2, 0,2,1,1,0, 0,2,1,2,2, 1,1,1,1,2, 1,2,1,0,0 };
    double[][] input={
             {1,1,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {1,1,1,0,0, 0,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,1,1,1,0, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,1,1,1, 0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,

             {1,0,0,0,0, 1,1,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,1,0,0,0, 1,1,1,0,0, 0,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,1,0,0, 0,1,1,1,0, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,1,1,1, 0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,

             {0,0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 1,1,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0,0, 1,1,1,0,0, 0,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,1,1,1,0, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,1,1,1, 0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,0} ,

             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 1,1,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0,0, 1,1,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,1,1,1,0, 0,0,1,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,1,1,1, 0,0,0,1,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,0,1} ,

             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 1,1,0,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,0,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,1,1,1,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,1,1,0} ,
             {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,1} ,

    };
```

What I mean by "fails" is that, I know there is at least one solution available which has all integer values but my implementation gives me fraction values.

Comment: I suggest you put the claimed solution into Jama and Common Maths and check that it is indeed a solution. It seems unlikely that two different programs make the same mistake.

Comment: Thanks @Jitse Niesen.. I'm sure it is one of the solutions. So if I put it back it will prove to be a solution. But I know there is one solution with all integer values. Can I force Jama or Commons Math to get that solution or get all possible solutions?